# bash script read file variables into local variables

Tags: bash, variables, file-io

I have a config file with the following content:

msgs.config:

```
tmsg:This is Title Message!
t1msg:This is T1Message.    
t2msg:This is T2Message.    
pmsg:This is personal Message!
```

I am writing a bash script that reads the msgs.config file variables and stores them into local variables. I will use these throughout the script. Due to permission I do not want to use the `.` method (source).

```
tmsg
t1msg
t2msg
pmsg
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Due to permission I do not want to use the . method (source)*  not sure how that would help, but you only need read permission to use `source`, and if you can't read it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":"
while read name value
do
    # Check value for sanity?  Name too?
    eval $name="$value"
done < $config_file
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Alternatively, you can use an associative array:

```
declare -A keys
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":"
while read name value
do
    keys[$name]="$value"
done < $config_file
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Now you can refer to `${keys[tmsg]}` etc to access the variables.  Or, if the list of variables is fixed, you can map the values to variables:

```
tmsg="${keys[tmsg]}"
```

Comment: No need to save `oldIFS`; you can just restrict the change in `IFS` to the `read` command with `while IFS=: read name value`. Also, use `declare "$name=$value` instead of `eval`.

Comment: thanks for all the help. You are suggesting:                   

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=":"
while IFS=: read name value
do
 declare "$name=$value"
done < $config_file

Comment: @thegreat078: The suggestion is to avoid `oldIFS` altogether and just use: `while IFS=':' read name value` in the loop (so you don't need to reset IFS after the loop). That's reasonable, assuming it works. And if the `declare $name="$value"` notation works (I've no reason to think it doesn't, but was stuck on a machine with Bash 3.2—which does not have associative arrays), then that is definitely a lot less error prone than `eval` (which is almost always playing with fire, but is sometimes necessary; OTOH, Bash has done a lot to make it less necessary than it once was, which is A Good Thing™!)

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: Okay so i just tried it. declare $name="$value" did not work in my bash. I used eval and it worked fine. I guess this may vary from machine to machine. Thanks for all the help. I am unable to vote until I get 15 reputations.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file and store the values-

```
i=0
config_file="/path/to/msgs.config"

while read line
do
  if [ ! -z "$line" ]  #check if the line is not blank
  then
   key[i]=`echo $line|cut -d':' -f1`  #will extract tmsg from 1st line and so on
   val[i]=`echo $line|cut -d':' -f2`  #will extract "This is Title Message!" from line 1 and so on
   ((i++))
  fi
done < $config_file
```

Access the array variables as `${key[0]}`,`${key[1]}`,.... and `${val[0]}`,`${val[1]}`...

Answer (score 1):

In case you change your mind about `source`:

```
source <( sed 's/:\(.*\)/="\1"/' msgs.config )
```

This does not work if any of your values have double quotes.